# Belongs on careers.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs

From time to time people post "Please hire me!" requests on /stackoverflow.com ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544117/please-help-me-to-find-freelancer-websites)). These are closed, usually, as "Not a real question," or something like that. In the spirit of "belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com," should there also be a "Belongs on careers.stackoverflow.com?"

Comment: Please hire me! PLeeeeease. I want 100k a year and I just finished my undergrad degree. I heard you can make a lot of $$$ in computers!

Comment: "Belongs in trade school"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like "moving" a question there will work.. Even if it did technically work (if careers.SO was based on the same engine), moving someones question to a site that requires you to pay is rather crappy

A better solution would be to simply add a comment informing the person that SO isn't an appropriate place to ask for a job, recommend they have a look at http://careers.stackoverflow.com and vote-to-close the question as "Not a real question"

Comment: I ageee it probably can't be "moved." But I wonder if the "correct" reply could be automated a bit.

Answer (score 4):

It occurs to me that the other "belongs on..." links eventually move the question. With careers (and specifically with charging users on careers), this couldn't work. There would need to be a kind of purgatory, "Insert 25¢ to continue."¹

¹ Is anyone here old enough to remember payphones? Or payphones which cost 25¢?

Comment: I remember payphone that were free if you handled them correctly...

Comment: all that payphone was looking for someone to rub it the right way.

Answer (score 2):

My gut reaction is "no, those posts are totally inappropriate and should be killed with haste." However, it would serve to drum up sales of the careers service, so maybe Jeff and the gang would want that.

Answer (score 1):

If you had just paid $99 for your CV to be displayed on a site, do you really want it being picked up by the kind of recruiter that spam a forum?

Comment: Most of the "job questions" on SO seem to be from job seekers rather than recruiters. Perhaps the recruiter posts get killed faster, though...

Comment: You are correct, job seekers should be pointed at careers. So often forums get plagued by idiot recruiters.

Comment: The shady recruiter issue *will* be a problem for careers, but I doubt this feature proposal will make it significantly worse.